# function with for loop for removing class

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```js
HB.formButtons.deactivatingButton = function(element) {
    element.parent().removeClass(HB.formButtons.SUBMIT_BUTTON_STYLE);
}
```

and than I call it as follow everytime I need it:

```
HB.formButtons.deactivatingButton($(HB.personalDetails.SUBMIT_CHANGE_PASSWORD_SELECTOR));
HB.formButtons.deactivatingButton($(HB.personalDetails.CANCEL_CHANGE_PASSWORD_SELECTOR));
```

Is there a way of calling it once (passing as many parameters) and perhaps introduce a loop in `HB.formButtons.deactivatingButton`?

Comment: you can add the classes that you want to deactivate in an array and then pass the array inside the function to iterate

Comment: why do you need a loop if selector is a class selector or tagName selector then it will return a collection if you apply anything on that selector that will be applied on each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely possible as follows:

```
HB.formButtons.deactivatingButton = function(elementsArray) {

    if($.isArray(elementsArray))
    {
        $.each( elementsArray, function( index, element){
            element.parent().removeClass(HB.formButtons.SUBMIT_BUTTON_STYLE);
        });
    }
}
```

And call this function only once as follows:

```
    var elementsArray = [$(HB.personalDetails.SUBMIT_CHANGE_PASSWORD_SELECTOR),
$(HB.personalDetails.CANCEL_CHANGE_PASSWORD_SELECTOR)];

    //call the function
    HB.formButtons.deactivatingButton(elementsArray);
```